# installation of package "collapsibleTree" had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, shiny

When I am trying to install "**collapsibleTree**" package in shiny server through console(putty), I am getting had non-zero exit status error. Though the installation in local RStudio happened smoothly and I can use the package to build the chart in shiny App but through console it failed to install in shiny server.

I even tried this command *install.packages("collapsibleTree", dependencies = TRUE)* but received same error. Any workaround to resolve the same.

## Error in detail

```
* installing *source* package ‘rgexf’ ...
** package ‘rgexf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-
protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -
D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c edges.analysis.c -o edges.analysis.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-
z,relro -o rgexf.so edges.analysis.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgexf/libs
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘$.igraph’, ‘$.igraph.es’, ‘$.igraph.vs’, ‘$<-.igraph’, 
‘$<-.igraph.es’, ‘$<-.igraph.vs’, ‘*.igraph’, ‘+.igraph’, ‘-.igraph’, 
‘[.communities’, ‘[.igraph’, ‘[.igraph.es’, ‘[.igraph.vs’, ‘[<-.igraph’, 
‘[<-.igraph.es’, ‘[<-.igraph.vs’, ‘[[.communities’, ‘[[.igraph’, 
‘[[.igraph.es’, ‘[[.igraph.vs’, ‘[[<-.igraph.es’, ‘[[<-.igraph.vs’, 
‘as.dendrogram.communities’, ‘as.hclust.communities’, ‘as.igraph.igraphHRG’, 
‘as_ids.igraph.es’, ‘as_ids.igraph.vs’, ‘as_phylo.communities’, 
‘c.igraph.es’, ‘c.igraph.vs’, ‘cohesion.cohesiveBlocks’, ‘cohesion.igraph’, 
‘compare.communities’, ‘compare.default’, ‘compare.membership’, 
‘difference.igraph’, ‘difference.igraph.es’, ‘difference.igraph.vs’, 
‘groups.communities’, ‘groups.default’, ‘intersection.igraph’, 
‘intersection.igraph.es’, ‘intersection.igraph.vs’, ‘length.cohesiveBl [... 
 truncated]
 Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) :
 shared object ‘igraph.so’ not found
 Error : package ‘igraph’ could not be loaded
 ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rgexf’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgexf’
ERROR: dependency ‘rgexf’ is not available for package ‘DiagrammeR’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/DiagrammeR’
ERROR: dependency ‘DiagrammeR’ is not available for package ‘data.tree’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/data.tree’
ERROR: dependency ‘data.tree’ is not available for package ‘collapsibleTree’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/collapsibleTree’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmprLWn1R/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("collapsibleTree", dependencies = TRUE) :
installation of package ‘rgexf’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("collapsibleTree", dependencies = TRUE) :
installation of package ‘DiagrammeR’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("collapsibleTree", dependencies = TRUE) :
installation of package ‘data.tree’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("collapsibleTree", dependencies = TRUE) :
installation of package ‘collapsibleTree’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Obviously the issue is not being able to load `igraph`. what happens if you install and attach `igraph`?

Comment: I tried installing igraph first as well. Got same issue - In install.packages("igraph") : installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: could you try install from source?`install.packages("igraph", type = 'source')`. If it works .so file will be generated in the process.